# Ionic3 - how to pass selected value to event using ion-select and ion-option?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to pass employee id on change of ion-option. I tried this, but it is not working, please tell me in case of any mistakes
Here is my code:

```
<ion-label>Employee</ion-label>
<ion-select formControlName="employee">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" (ionChange)="selectEmployee($event, employee)">{{ employee.FirstName + " " + employee.MiddleName + " " + employee.LastName }}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

employee.ts file code:

```
selectEmployee(event, employee)
{
    alert(employee.EMP_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct event to use with `ion-option` is [`ionSelect`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/option/Option/#output-events).

```
 <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" (ionSelect)="selectEmployee($event, employee)">{{ employee.FirstName + " " + employee.MiddleName + " " + employee.LastName }}</ion-option>
```

*This will be fired when user selects the specific option.*

Since you are using reactive form, you can use `valueChanges` observable of the formGroup or formControl.

```
 this.yourForm.controls['employee'].valueChanges.subscribe(data=>console.log(data));
```

*This will get called after user clicks OK in the select form.*

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `ngModel` to pass values on option selected. Below the object of the option selected is passed via ngModel using a variable named `emp`. This variable should be declared in your `employee.ts` globally, that you may use it throughout the class.

**employee.html**

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="emp" interface="popover">          
   <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]=employee>{{ employee.FirstName + " " + employee.MiddleName + " " + employee.LastName }}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

If you need to do anything when select option changes like populating new design contents based on the option selected or if you need to write any instant logic depending upon the option selected, then you can include `ionChange` inside the `select` tag and call a function on ts class like below.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="emp" interface="popover" (ionChange)="onEmpSelected()">          
   <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]=employee>{{ employee.FirstName + " " + employee.MiddleName + " " + employee.LastName }}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

If you do some logic without the necessity of a global variable, the you can get rid of `ngModel`, and do it inside the function alone, then you should use `ionSelect` inside the `option` tag by removing `ionChange` from the `select` tag like below.

```
<ion-select interface="popover">
   <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" (ionSelect)="onEmpSelected(employee)">{{ employee.FirstName + " " + employee.MiddleName + " " + employee.LastName }}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

**employee.ts**

Declare `emp` globally and use it wherever necessary if using `ngModel`. The whole employee object would be available on your `employee.ts` file. And if you are calling the function using `ionChange`, write your logic in the function you've called.

```
onEmpSelected() {

// write your logic here

}
```

And if you are using `ionSelect` without `ngModel`, then the selected option data would be available locally to be accessed by the function like below.

```
onEmpSelected(employee) {

// write your logic here

}
```